# Intent Not working in MenuInflater and with Buttons

Tags: android, android-intent

So I was trying to work on graphics and wanted to use intent to switch between activities and its not the first time I am doing it but I really cannot find the error. So I am posting the code for my mainactivity and manifest here. Please tell me the cause of the problem

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //fullscreen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent p = new Intent("com.example.menuinflater.GFX");
            startActivity(p);

        }
    });
}
```

and Manifest looks something like this:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".About"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_about"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.About" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Prefs"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_about" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.Prefs" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GFX"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_gfx" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

I hope that makes clear where am I going wrong and I would want an answer with explanation. I would highly appreciate any solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading the basic training pages on developer.android.com, they contain alot of basic and useful information.

About your specific problem, this link ought to help:   http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

The intent should be like this:
Intent p = new Intent(this, GFX.class);